# How to configure ibm cloud application to Godaddy domain

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

This issue is become a little complicated to me.
I´m using GoDaddy for my DNS Host and trying to configure my domain in IBM Cloud Application.
I followed the IBM Cloud documentation in [Adding and using a custom domain](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-custom-domains).

My doubt is in how to configure the CNAME in GoDaddy to change my domain from **myapp.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud** to **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)**

The redirection options is working fine for http request (https is not working) when i type **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)** and then redirect to **myapp.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud** but just show my domain in url not.

Any idea to how fix it?

The configuration that I tried and it´s redirecting from **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)** to IBM Cloud App in GoDaddy is

```
Tipo    Nome completo   Valor                                               TTL             Ações
A       @               Parked                                              600 segundos    Editar
CNAME   <mydomain>.com  <myapp>.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud                 1/2 hora        Editar
CNAME   www             @                                                   1 hora          Editar
NS      @               ns09.domaincontrol.com                              1 hora  
NS      @               ns10.domaincontrol.com                              1 hora  
SOA     @               Servidor de nome principal: ns09.domaincontrol.com. 1 hora
```

In IBM Cloud I added my domain in Domains and also in routes I added [www].[mydomain.com]

Comment: Are you using Cloud Foundry? You linked to the CF docs, but you tagged your question with IBM Cloud Infrastructure.

Comment: Hello @data_henrik, I´m using IBM Cloud Foundry. I remove the tag infrastructure. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand the question. What exactly is the problem, which redirection is not working? Have you waited for the DNS records getting updated (from minutes to days)?

Comment: Hello @data_henrik the redirection is working. When I type in browser **www.mydomain.com** will be redirected to **myapp.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud**. What I´m expecting is something when I type **www.mydomain.com** don´t redirect but show the application in IBM Cloud directly (without change the URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several searchs in the internet and also in StackOverflow and the contribution of @data_henrik finally I found the right configuration for DNS between GoDaddy and IBM Cloud (Cloud Foundry Application).

As mentioned before, is necessary to follow the steps [Adding and using a custom domain](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-custom-domains) as bellow:

1. [Adding a custom domain from the IBM Cloud console](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-custom-domains#custom-domain-console)
2. [Adding the route with the custom domain to an app](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-custom-domains#adding-the-route-with-the-custom-domain-to-an-app) - in my case I create the route as **www** + **mydomain.com** if you left the first field in blank, the URL will not be resolved by IBM Cloud Domain Service. Another important information is that IBM Cloud change the name of my original application route because in my case the name was the same of my domain (intersting).
3. In GoDaddy, the right configuration are bellow:

| Type | Complete Name | Value | TTL | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | @ | 169.62.254.80 | 600 sec | The @ parameter must be pointed to the custom-domain server IP, in my case us-south server |
| CNAME | **mydomain**.com | custom-domain.us-south.cf.cloud.ibm.com | 1 hour | As mentioned before by @data_henrik |
| CNAME | www | @ | 1 hour | Just redirect www to the current domain |
| NS | @ | ns09.domaincontrol.com | 1 hour | Default |
| NS | @ | ns10.domaincontrol.com | 1 hour | Default |
| SOA | @ | Server main name: ns09.domaincontrol.com. | 1 hour | Default |

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because you need to set the CNAME record to the domain as instructed in the IBM Cloud docs which you linked to. It is misleading, but you have to follow the instructions literally.

Set your CNAME to **custom-domain.us-south.cf.cloud.ibm.com**. That is the IBM-internal resolver which would map the incoming request to your configured route.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several options to configure CNAME in GoDaddy to IBM Cloud. My last configuration it was that:

In GoDaddy DNS Server:

```
Type        Complete Name   Value                                                           TTL
A           @                           Parked                                                          600 segundos    Editar
CNAME   mydomain.com    custom-domain.us-south.cf.cloud.ibm.com 1 hora  
CNAME   www                 @                                                                   1 hora  
NS          @                           ns09.domaincontrol.com                                  1 hora  
NS          @                           ns10.domaincontrol.com                                  1 hora  
SOA @                           Servidor de nome principal: ns09.domaincontrol.com. 1 hora
```

In IBM Cloud:

1. In Account, I included domain **mydomain.com**; and
2. In App Route, I include as ** *.mydomain.com**, in order to associate to **www** according with the documentation.

What is wrong?